# Mobile backend starter continuous query never returns

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

I've written an Android client for a mobile backend starter app according to [this](http://bradabrams.com/2013/05/google-io-2013-session-overview-from-nothing-to-nirvana-in-minutes-cloud-backend-for-your-android-application-building-geek-serendipity/) tutorial.  Everything works up to the section implementing `Continuous Queries`.

I've written a query and I'm calling it from the correct place in the code (`onPostCreate()`), however the query never returns any data.

I don't believe this is an authentication problem because I'm able to make other calls successfully.

Here is the code which never returns a result:

```
CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>> handler = new CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(List<CloudEntity> results) {
            for (CloudEntity entity : results) {
                UserLocation loc = new UserLocation(entity);
                mUserLocations.remove(loc);
                mUserLocations.add(loc);
                drawMarkers();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    CloudQuery query = new CloudQuery("UserLocation");
    query.setLimit(50);
    query.setSort(CloudEntity.PROP_UPDATED_AT, Order.DESC);
    query.setScope(Scope.FUTURE_AND_PAST);
    getCloudBackend().list(query, handler);
```

With the debugger I've verified that the `getCloudBackend().list()` line executes, but the `onComplete()` method is never hit, and neither is `onError()`.

Here is an example of a call that works perfectly:

```
UserLocation self = new UserLocation(super.getAccountName(),
                gh.encode(mCurrentLocation));
        getCloudBackend().update(self.asEntity(), updateHandler);
```

Essentially, `getCloudBackend().update()` works, while `getCloudBackend().list()` does not.

I should also add that I've downloaded the full source from the github repo linked in the tutorial, and the same problem exists with that code.
I've also tried re-deploying the backend server multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I have finally fixed the problem! The issue is both in the manifest and in the class `GCMIntentService.java`

In the manifest the GCM is registered as a service and belongs to a package. By default this service is a part of the default package `com.google.cloud.backend.android`. When you create a new package and have all your client code in there, you need to move the `GCMIntentService.java` class into that new package and in the manifest modify the service and broadcast receiver

```
<service android:name="yourpackagename.GCMIntentService" />
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="yourpackagename" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Any other permission that comes with the default package name should also be updated to the main package name. This doesn't need to be modified if you're only going to use that one default package that comes with the mobile backend starter.

Regarding the GoogleAuthIOException I received that as well initially. So I redid all the steps to enable GCM and authentication. Things to keep in mind though are that I still followed the tutorial  and went with `Web Application -> Generic` when registering the GCM server key and Web Client ID. Also another key thing to keep in mind when registering for the Android Client ID is that with your SHA1 fingerprint it also needs a package name. Again the package name has to be your main client package if you're using more than one package for your project. You can get the project number that goes in the Consts.java (and it's required to register GCM) from the old Google API console  and the project ID from the new cloud console. The Web client ID also goes in the Consts.java file and also in that same file you have to enable auth by changing

```
public static final boolean IS_AUTH_ENABLED = false;
```

to

```
public static final boolean IS_AUTH_ENABLED = true;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I sort of stumbled on this as well, the key is that the GCMIntentService class *must* be in the same package that is used to register for GCM and get an API key.  As far as I can tell this is not documented anywhere.

Comment: Yes it isn't and it should be. It'll save lots of other people headache.

Answer (score 0):

So I am also getting the SAME EXACT problem you are. `getCloudBackend().update()` works for me, and not only with the geohasher class, I also tried to send updates to the cloud with `myLocation.toString()` where myLocation is a LatLng and it gets updated fine.

Sorry for not giving you the actual solution to your problem. It's a really odd situation that the same exact code worked in the Google I/O demo but not when we (and I followed the tutorial very thoroughly) actually try it out. I feel that this is a server problem if anything.

Comment: I agree this is probably a problem on the server.  I think I'm going to try importing the backend code and see if I can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this -- sorry you are having a problem.  THe most likely problem is in configuring GCM.   Can you verify you have GCM enabled on the project and all the setup steps where done correctly?   Maybe try to send a message and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I started over from scratch, and unfortunately I've done something wrong with the authentication setup because I'm getting GoogleAuthIOException's now, *however*, I am seeing a log statement that says the query is being requested, and I was not seeing this before.  I'm going to edit my question to show where I think the problem was.

Comment: If you can confirm that what I mention in my edit above would cause the problem I've described then I can mark your answer as correct.